# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadExceptionproblem

Tags: java, android, sockets

I want to open a Socket in my Android app, which reads a file from a server.

I have the server running on the same computer as the emulator, and I have tested this outside of Android to make sure I did not have firewall issues or other problems making the connection.

Below is the code I have a problem with. It will print the IP address followed by *streamm000*. At this point it throws a `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Further, the other `toast` gives me `NULL`.

Here is my code...

```
    toast("IP="+getIP());

    try {
        toast("created stream00000");
        so=new Socket("10.50.1.25", 80);
        toast("created stream111111");
        oos=new ObjectOutputStream(so.getOutputStream());
        toast("created stream2222");
        dos=new DataOutputStream(so.getOutputStream());
        //oos.close();
        toast("created stream33333");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        toast(e.getCause() +"problem with this bla bla is opensteam");
        toast(e.getMessage()+"problem with this bla bla is opensteam");
        Log.v(e+"problem ","with this bla bla is opensteam");
    }
```

Comment: If your question has been answered, or if it is no longer valid, please 'tick' to choose the most appropriate answer so everyone knows that the problem has been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `NetworkOnMainThreadException` is thrown because, in Honeycomb and higher, you are forced to perform network operations on Threads that are separate to the main display `Thread`.

See the description here... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

My suggestion, therefore, would be to move your code into a new `Runnable` class, and then create a `Thread` to execute it.

Comment: I will try that. Thank you. I just put it in AsyncTask and doInBackground but still samer results. I will try the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make much sense to be able to answer your question. But looks like you are doing network operations on the main UI thread. This is not allowed in the newer API levels. It will throw this exception when you try to do this.

You will need to spawn a different thread, and do the network operation there.

Comment: That was it! I then had to deal with my print outs. It did not like them in a thread.  THANK YOU!!!